# What function satisfy: $f(x)+f^{-1}(x)=2x$?

Tags: functions, inverse

What function satisfy: $f(x)+f^{-1}(x)=2x$?

I have tried to substitute $x=f(x)$ to get $f^{(2)}(x)+1=2f(x)$ and subsequently plug in values to try to find $f(x)$ but to no avail.
Please help thank you in advance!

Comment: Merely observing the function _y = x_ satisfies the condition

Comment: Let $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)=x$.

Comment: Maybe from a geometric point of view ?

Comment: Let $f(x)=x+c$, where $c$ is any constant.  Then $f^{-1}(x)=x-c$.

Comment: Two points are unclear: 1. What is the expected mapping of $f(x)$ ? I guess OP wants $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ but can't be absolutely certain. 2. Does OP wants a complete solution, or just a single example?

Comment: Sorr @AbelCheung you are right! How do I prove that $f(x)=x+c$ is really the only solution function that satisfy the above criteria

Comment: One can get a small step further by substituting $x = 0$ and $x = \pm f(0)$ and see what can be derived. But I didn't attempt to think clearly beyond that.

Answer (score 7):

I think that I can prove that (under some conditions),
linear functions $f(x) = x + c$ are the only solutions.

The equation (implicitly) assumes that
$f$ has an inverse function $f^{-1}$ with the same domain as $f$.
I am only considering bijective functions $f :  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ here. Note that such functions are strictly monotonic if and only if they are continuous.

My claim is:

> Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and bijective
>   such that
>   $$ \tag 1
> f(x) + f^{-1}(x) = 2x \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb R \, .
> $$
>
> Then $f(x) = x+f(0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

If $f(x) \equiv x$ then we are done, so let's assume that $f(a) \ne a$
for some $a \in \mathbb R$. Without loss of generality we can
assume that $f(a) > a$, otherwise consider $g := f^{-1}$ instead of $f$.
So
$$
  d := f(a) - a > 0 \, .
$$

It follows from $(1)$ that
$$
f^{(2)}(x) = 2 f(x) - x \tag 2
$$
and then via induction for all $n \in \mathbb N$
$$
f^{(n)}(x) = n f(x) - (n-1)x \, .
\tag 3 
$$
In particular,
$$
   f^{(n)}(a) = n\,f(a) - (n-1) a = n (a+d) - (n-1) a = a + nd \, .
$$
Applying the same
calculation to $f^{-1}$ gives
$$
f^{(-n)}(a) = a - nd \, .
$$
Together it follows that
$$
 f(a + kd) = a + (k+1)d \tag 4
$$
for all $k \in \mathbb Z$.

$f$ is strictly monotonic, so $(4)$ implies that each
interval from $a + kd$ to $a + (k+1)d$ is mapped onto the "next" interval:
$$
 f \bigl([a + kd, a + (k+1)d]\bigr) = [a + (k+1)d, a + (k+2)d] \tag {5}
$$

Now let $x \in \mathbb R$ and choose $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that
$$
 a + kd \le x < a + (k+1)d \, . \tag 6
$$
For all $n \in \mathbb N$ it follows from $(5)$ and $(6)$ that
$$
x + (n-1)d \le a + (k+n)d \le f^{(n)}(x) \le a + (k+n+1)d \le x + (n+1) d \, .
$$
Substituting this in $(3)$ gives
$$
x + (n-1)d \le n f(x) - (n-1)x \le x + (n+1) d
$$
or 
$$
\frac{nx + (n-1)d}{n} \le f(x) \le \frac{n x + (n+1)d}{n} \, .
$$
Finally, $n \to \infty$ gives
$$
 x + d \le f(x) \le x + d \, .
$$

Comment: How does (2) follow from (1)?

Comment: Never mind, I see. I was thinking about it totally wrong.

Comment: why is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @hellofriends: I *assume* that $f$ is continuous (or equivalently, strictly monotonic).

Comment: @MartinR yes I got a similar question where $f$ is increasing and I would like to see how $f$ must be continuous

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660285/to-find-all-strictly-monotone-functions-f0-infty-rightarrow-0-infty

Comment: @hellofriends: An increasing function can only have jump discontinuities. And those cannot occur if $f$ is surjective. – That's why I said that a bijective function is continuous if (and only if) it is strictly monotonic.

Comment: @MartinR I didn't understand from this step For all $n \in \mathbb N$ it follows from $(5)$ and $(6)$ that
$
x + (n-1)d \le a + (k+n)d \le f^{(n)}(x) \le a + (k+n+1)d \le x + (n+1) d \, .$

How did you write this step?

Comment: @mathophile: Consider the intervals $I_k = [a+kd, a+(k+1)d)$. (5) states that $f$ maps $I_k$ to $I_{k+1}$. So if $x \in I_k$ then $f^{(n)}(x) \in I_{k+n} = [a+(k+n)d, a+(k+n+1)d)$. Also $a+(k+n)d = a+(k+1)d +(n-1)d \ge x+(n-1)d$ and $a+(k+n+1)d = a+kd + (n+1)d \le x+(n+1)d$.

Comment: @MartinR Also can you tell me how did you obtained equation $(4)$ ?

Comment: @mathophile: Previously it was shown that $f^{(n)}(a) = a+nd$ holds for all integers $n$. Therefore $f(a+kd) = f(f^{(k)}(a)) = f^{(k+1)}(a) = a+(k+1)d$.

Comment: @mathophile: Is everything clear now?

Comment: @Martin R Yes, Thanks