# Find all strictly monotone $f:(0,+\infty) \to (0, +\infty)$ such that $f(\frac{x^2}{f(x)})=x.$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

Find all strictly monotone functions $f:(0,+\infty) \to (0,+\infty)$ such that
$$f\left(\frac{x^2}{f(x)}\right)=x.$$

My try: it is clear that $f$ is surjective. And because it is monotone it must also be injective. Therefore we can take $f^{-1}$ from both sides: $x^2 = f(x) \cdot f^{-1}(x)$.
We can take $x = f(y)$ (because of surjectivity) and get that: $\frac{f(y)}{y} = \frac{f(f(y))}{f(y)}$.
So, if we define $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ we have that $g(y) = g\big(f(y)\big)$ and I was hoping to prove that $g$ is injective so we would have $f(x) = x$ only. But I couldn't figure that last step. There may be a better way to deal with this problem.

EDIT: There is another solution on AOPS, [problem 312](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h350187p3005173).

Comment: Can try to get $f \circ g$ injective ?

Comment: it seems to me that this would be enough, but how?

Comment: but $f(g(x))$ would be a constant. Wait, that kinda proves $g$ is not injective. :(

Comment: A distinction maybe $f$ growing and $f$ stricly decreasing (its ok because positive $g$ do so))   and try a contradiction if it isn't constant (using strict monotony). I'm exploring this idea

Comment: may be better to assume g is not a constant and get a contradiction

Comment: Note that for any $\lambda>0$ the function $f(x) = \lambda x$ satisfies the condition, so you will not be able to conclude that $f$ is the identity.

Comment: I would suspect that a better direction is to show that ${f(x) \over x}$ is a constant?

Comment: Hint: 

If $g$ is not constant.

 1. $f$ is strictly decreasing so $g$ is injective absurde
 2. $f$ strictly increasing  (try to compare to $x$, seeking idea on that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $h : x \mapsto \ln\big(f(e^x)\big) $.
You need to prove that $h(x)+h^{-1}(x)=2x$ (I leave it to you because it is simple). we have that $h$ is increasing (also easy to prove by contradiction or another way).

Now consider $ n \in \mathbb N$ and define $r_n:= h^n(x)$ and $s_n:=h^{-n}(x)$.

We have:
$$r_{n+1}+r_{n-1}=h(r_n)+h^{-1}(r_n)=2r_n \text,$$
and similarly
$$s_{n-1} +s_{n+1}=2s_n\text.$$

Therefore:
$$ r_n= \lambda(x) + \mu(x)n $$
(and $ s_n= \alpha(x) + \beta(x)n $).

Now, let's prove that $h$ is continuous:
let $x , y \in \mathbb R $ such that $x>y$.
$h(x) - h(y) < h(x) - h(y) + h^{-1}(x) - h^{-1}(y)$ , because $h^{-1}$ is also increasing.
Therefore $h(x) - h(y) < 2(x-y)$ or $|h(x) - h(y) |< 2|x-y|$.
Thus $h$ is continuous.

I wasn't able to proceed from here, but given the continuity you can use the [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1336481/229831)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1505613/229831) by [Martin R](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42969/martin-r).

Comment: I feel like it misses solutions like $f(x) = 2x$, but it got some good stuff. I think if $h(x) < x$ we have $r_{n+1} < r_n$

Comment: It must have, because $f(x) = \lambda x$ for $\lambda >0$ are also solutions.

Comment: yeah if $h(x) < x$ $(r_n)_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: @hellofriends: Generally a good idea to wait a day or two before accepting.

Comment: @copper.hat what do you think: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336481/what-function-satisfy-fxf-1x-2x

Comment: I will wait a day, if nothing changes I can use Mohammed M result with that question and get the answer

Comment: I will have another look and correct it first thing in the morning

Comment: it is ok, Martin's answer on the linked topic solves the equation for $h(x)$. Your answer is enough!

Comment: @MohammedM.Zerrak:  Note that $h(x) = x + c$ is also a solution (corresponding to $f(x) = \lambda x$).

Comment: @MohammedM.Zerrak:  Sorry, but I cannot follow your argument. Why is $(r_n)_n$ increasing if $h(x) < x$?

Comment: I have edited my post , in fact as you correctly stated , $r_n $ isn't increasing when $h(x) <x$

Answer (score 1):

Starting from $\frac{f(f(y))}{f(y)} = \frac{f(y)}{y}$:

For each fixed $y>0$, let $y_n=f^n(y)$, $n\in {\Bbb Z}$ be its orbit. The above condition on $f$ yields:
$$ \forall n \in {\Bbb Z}: \frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}=\frac{y_n}{y_{n-1}} =: \lambda(y)$$
for some $\lambda(y)>0$ independent of $n$. Thus, $f^n(y) = y \lambda(y)^n$ for all $n\in {\Bbb Z}$.
Monotonicity of $f$, whence of $f^n$, implies:
$$ 0<x<y \Rightarrow \forall n \in {\Bbb Z} : 0 < x \lambda(x)^n < y \lambda(y)^n$$
which can be satisfied iff $\lambda(x)=\lambda(y)$. Thus, $f(x) =\lambda x$ for some $\lambda>0$.